# Unexpected JS behavior when clearing input field value - STCombobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using some JQuery Combobox that you can check out here: https://simpletutorials.com/uploads/1860/demo/index.html

As you can see, you can start typing and get the results filtered.
However, once you have selected a value, when clicking on the arrow to open the list, no other values are shown anymore. So, if I want to change college/state, I need to manually clear the input value. I don't like this, so I want to modify it.

I changed that code and added this JS on the click event of the list:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('statesCombo-ddi').value='';"
```

This line basically finds the input by id and sets its value to an empty string. 
You can try out by looking for the td element having class "stc-button" (with Chrome, just focus on the arrow of the second combo box) and add my code to the tag.

===EDIT===
You can obtain the same results by adding this code directly to the input:

```
onclick="this.value=''"
```

===END EDIT===

This has a weird behavior:

1. If I SELECT an element from the list, it clears the value and everything works correctly.
2. If I TYPE some letters and then select a value from the list, no item is shown in the list after clicking.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using a regular dropdown? This is really kludgey with the spans and tables.

Comment: Of course, the reason is that a dropdown does not support typing and filtering for partially matching strings.

Comment: This plugin or whatever is assigning multiple elements with the same ID, to give you an example. I'd look for another plugin that does the same thing. There are a billion dropdown filter plugins.

Comment: Unfortunately I am into it and I am forced to correct it. It is too late to drop it

Comment: Understood. Just a heads up to be careful with this plugin. Good luck!

Comment: Which elements have the same ID?

Comment: @L0j1k Nevermind, found it. It was accidental and is being fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override one of the combo box methods to accomplish this:

```
STComboBox.prototype.filterAndResetSelected = function() {
    this.$('ddi').val('');
    this.filterList('');
    this.selectRow(0);
    this.$('ddl').scrollTop(0);
};
```

Does this help?

The unminified code is provided, is relatively small (12kb) and is fairly well commented, so you could make this modification directly to the source if you'd like.

Edit: Fixed to clear the input value (as indicated in the comment below)

Comment: Thanks, that does not fix the problem: if I select from the list without typing, I get the result I expect, but if I type some letters and select, then I don't

Comment: Just edited to reset the input value. It basically resets the filter value in the input box each time the button is clicked. Is that what you were looking for? Did you also want to scroll to the item previously selected once the list opens?

Comment: Currently, the list only contains items matching the previously inserted text. Actually, I would like to see the full list every time I click on the arrow.

Comment: OK, I think I've got a good fix for it. Can you confirm? Demo [here](https://simpletutorials.com/uploads/1860/demo2/index.html)

Comment: Yes! What do I need to change?

Comment: @Manu The combobox has been [fixed and updated](https://simpletutorials.com/c/2002/STComboBox%3A+A+Lightweight+jQuery+Combo+Box) and is ready for download. Can you confirm it's now working as desired?

Comment: Perfect, now it does work as expected, thanks. However, there is still one point. I have multiple comboboxes in my page. If I open one of them, I don't select any item, and I click on another combobox (either the input field or the arrow), the firstly opened list doesn't disappear.

Comment: This has now been fixed and is ready for download from [the site](https://simpletutorials.com/c/2002/STComboBox%3A+A+Lightweight+jQuery+Combo+Box) or [repo](https://github.com/jasonprogrammer/stcombobox).

Answer (score 1):

By reading the source and doing a little debugging with Chrome's inspector (`Control+Shift+i`), you can find the particular ID of the element you need to clear (`#collegesCombo-ddi`) in order to clear the input box. Once you've found the element's ID you need to clear (and being very careful with plugins that assign multiple elements with the same ID, which is not allowed in the standard, and an indicator of poorly-written code):

`$('#collegesCombo-ddi').val('');`

Comment: Thanks, but I put your code in the onclick attribute and it does not seem to work: undefined type error

Comment: Open the inspector, paste in my suggestion into the console. You will see that it indeed works to clear the input. I can't debug the error you're having, but the message indicates that you're possibly trying to select something which isn't an element.

Comment: Right, but try this. 1. select a value from the dropdown 2. run your code, 3. open the dropdown again. Just one element shows up, i.e. the one you previously selected. That's my issue.

Comment: In my version of Chromium (Version 40.0 on Linux), it presents the whole list after clearing the element. What browser are you using? Again, this plugin is kinda ugly and hacky, so definitely there are probably browser issues that will get in your way.

Comment: OK, that's bad. It does not work for me on Chrome 40.0.2214.115, it does on Firefox 35. Windows platform. Any idea?

Comment: Now that's very interesting. I'm using x.2214.111. This sucks, but if it won't work in different browsers, then it's best to find another way, since there's nothing you can personally do (except change the code) to make it work. I debug website code every morning for work, and really the only solution is to use different code. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to modify the library and put it in the list of "DO NOT USE". I hope to end up somewhere working.

Comment: Good luck to you. BTW it's an interesting website you're working on.

Comment: Thanks. In fact it's a pity having to cope with this issue, while there are others much more interesting on my project.